# How to pipe stderr to my StreamWriter object?

Tags: python

I have an object of type [StreamWriter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-stream.html#streamwriter). How can I pipe stderr to it?
In Node i would do something like: `stderr.pipe(my_stream)`.

Answer (score 2):

In Python, you can simply assign your stream as [sys.stderr](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.stderr).

```py
import sys

my_stream = StreamWriter()

sys.stderr = my_stream
```

Although, using contextlib's [redirect_stderr](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.redirect_stderr) function can be more manageable as it only temporarily redirects a stream to stderr.

```py
from contextlib import redirect_stderr

my_stream = StreamWriter()

with redirect_stderr(my_stream):
    # Any output to stderr will be redirected to my_stream within this block
```

Comment: Thanks, and what if I wanted stderr to pass data to my custom stream AND stay unchanged? Because that's my problem, I want it to be the original sys.stderr and as an addition, also send any data to my custom stream.